# S3 Download from a specific folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have two folders inside my s3 bucket.
How can I download all the files only from only bucket_one.

This is the code I am using to download from bucket.
Now I want to download from a folder inside that bucket.

```
GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest(BucketName(),KeyName());
       S3Object object = s3Client.getObject(request);
       S3ObjectInputStream objectContent = object.getObjectContent();
       IOUtils.copy(objectContent, new FileOutputStream(System.getProperty("user.home")+"//downloads//"+KeyName()));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just indicate the full path of the folder in question

Change your `BucketName()` method to be something like `folderName()` which will be `bucketName() + "/" + <yourfolder> + "/"`

the "/" is important at the end otherwise S3 will search for a file within your bucket root folder

You can use the same to go deeper in your folder structure : `bucketName() + "/" + <folder1> + "/" + <folder2> + "/"`

Answer (score 0):

The above answer provided by Frederic Henri is correct but you should not include `/` if `yourFolder` is the last folder .i.e, if directory is `<yourBucket>/<lvlOne>/<lvlTwo>/`, then at the end of folder `lvlTwo`, you should not include `\`

You can [list](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingObjectKeysUsingJava.html) all files in the bucket of a particular folder and download them individually or you may take a loot at [MultipleFileDownload interface](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/MultipleFileDownload.html)
in the [TransferManager](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html) class