# Download content of a specific folder from AWS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to AWS and facing difficulty downloading files from a specific folder in AWS. I know there is no folder concept in AWS.

I am able to download file which is there in root folder of the bucket by below code but not with in any specific folder:

```
String fileName = "savings.pdf";
private static String bucketName = "XXXXXX.statement";
S3Object fetchFile = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName.concat("APL420/"), fileName));
final BufferedInputStream i = new BufferedInputStream(fetchFile.getObjectContent());
InputStream objectData = fetchFile.getObjectContent();
Files.copy(objectData, new File(fileName).toPath()); 
objectData.close();
```

But not able to download all the contents of a folder in the bucket. Please suggest a proper way.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37226145/s3-download-from-a-specific-folder) answer but appending anything to bucketName is not notworking:

```
S3Object fetchFile = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName + "APL420/", fileName));
```

OR

```
S3Object fetchFile = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName + "/APL420/", fileName));
```

is not working.

Comment: How about `S3Object fetchFile = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, "/APL420/" + fileName));`?

Comment: This I get `The specified key doesnot exist`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't use slash at the end then it will work if key exist. S3 service append the slash by default.

Edited the solution as per @Michael comment. Using prefix in filename is the correct solution. Not in the bucket name.

```
S3Object fetchFile = s3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, "APL420/" + fileName));
```

Adding a snippet from S3RequestEndpointResolver:

```
private String getPathStyleResourcePath() {
  return bucketName + "/" + (key != null ? key : "");
}
```

Comment: Thanks abhilekh! I was under the impression that, I need to have '/' at the end of 'APL420' after reading the other answer. Such silly mistake. Thanks for saving my day

Comment: **If this works, it is essenially a bug in the library.**  Do not append the key prefix ("path") to the bucket name -- prepend it to the filename.  `Key = "APL420/" + Filename` is the *correct* solution, and yes, it needs a trailing slash.  The answer to the other question may work in some cases, but is also wrong in principle for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

getObject gets a **single** object stored in Amazon S3 under the specified bucket and key. Returns null if the specified constraints weren't met.

You might want to take a look at the [MultipleFileDownload](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/MultipleFileDownload.html) interface in the [TransferManager](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html) class instead.

Comment: Any code snipet on how to download multiple files from a specific folder using MultipleFileDownload would be great just to get me started